# RebaseData to read backup files

Tags: python, backup, rebase

So i am trying to read a .bak file, and from googling, it seems rebase is the way to go, however i keep getting traceback error

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:filepath", line 1, in 
from poster.encode import multipart_encode
File "C:filepath\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\poster_*init*_.py", line 4, in 
import poster.streaminghttp
File "C:filepath\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\poster\streaminghttp.py", line 58
print "send:", repr(value)
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

**Rebasedata code:**

```
from poster.encode import multipart_encode
from poster.streaminghttp import register_openers
import urllib2

#Register the streaming http handlers with urllib2

register_openers()

#Use multipart encoding for the input files

datagen, headers = multipart_encode({ 'files[]': open('example.bak', 'rb')})

#Create the request object

request = urllib2.Request('https://www.rebasedata.com/api/v1/convert', datagen, headers)

#Do the request and get the response

#Here the BAK file gets converted to CSV

response = urllib2.urlopen(request)

#Check if an error came back

if response.info().getheader('Content-Type') == 'application/json':
    print response.read()
    sys.exit(1)

#Write the response to /tmp/output.zip

with open('/tmp/output.zip', 'wb') as local_file:
    local_file.write(response.read())

print 'Conversion result successfully written to /tmp/output.zip!'
```

How do i actually get this script to run? thank you.
Note i replaced my original file path with "filepath"

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the `poster` module is trying to use the Python 2 type `print "x"` syntax instead of the Python 3 `print("x")` syntax.

You are possibly trying to use the wrong version of `poster`. There's a module called `poster3`, maybe give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the requests, because I am using python 3

```
import requests

response = requests.post('https://www.rebasedata.com/api/v1/convert', files={'files[]': open('PDVUPDATES.FDB','rb')})

# Write the response to /tmp/output.zip
with open('/tmp/outpuat.zip', 'wb') as local_file:
    b = bytes(response.text, 'utf-8')
    local_file.write(response.content)

print('Conversion result successfully written to /tmp/output.zip!')
```

Comment: Welcome. Please elaborate on how this strictly answers the question. As it is, your answer is a little thin by SO standards; please see [answer] for guidance.